# How do I make a multiline text field default to the number keypad?

Tags: flutter

I have a multiline text field that is to accept a list of numbers. If I set
`keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline` then the default keyboard changes to text after every enter key press. If I set `keyboardType: TextInputType.number` then the text field behaves as an single line (no effect of enter key).

How would I get both multiline and number?

Answer (score 0):

```
TextField(
   minLines: 2,
   maxLines: 3,
   keyboardType: TextInputType.number)
```

just add minLines or maxLines.

Comment: Nope, does not work - I already have the minLines and maxLines set. Did you check this?